# CSS3: Задать значение css свойства, используя значение атрибута другого тега средствами CSS3

Tags: css3, теги, атрибуты

**Например:** задать значение `color` тега `<a></a>`, используя значение атрибута `value` тега `<input />`:

```
<a>text</a>
<input type="text" value="red"/>
```

**P.S.** уже искал и решил, что нельзя, но вдруг недооценил css3...

И почему не работает даже [такая конструкция](http://jsfiddle.net/verhov/pCKUr/):

```
<input type="text" style="color: attr(value color)" value="#f00" />
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На данный момент `attr()` поддерживается только для свойства `content`. Смотрите таблицу совместимости на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fattr).

Comment: Это было в версии CSS 2.1, даже при переходе по вашей ссылке написано: **"The attr() expression can be used with any CSS property."**

Comment: В конец страницы проскрольте до **Browser Compatibility**. По спецификации может использоваться с любым. Но поддержка экспериментальна, и отсутствует можно сказать везде.

Comment: Да уж, ситуация то не очень. я думаю, если с атрибутами такая вот беда, то и надеяться на поддержку *взятия атрибутов с других элементов для использования в свойствах средствами css* говорить в ближайшее время не придется.